# django select data with filter over a inner table

Tags: mysql, django

I will select data over 2 joined tables with a filter over the inner table

Here my Models:

```
class tbl1(models.Model):
    id1 = models.AutoField(db_column='id1', primary_key=True)
    id2 = models.ForeignKey(tbl2, models.PROTECT, db_column='id2', blank=True, null=True)
    val = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=False)
    ...

class tbl2(models.Model):
    id2 = models.AutoField(db_column='id2', primary_key=True)
    order = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=False)
    ....
```

I need this SQL-Statement:

```
select id1, val
from tbl1
inner join tbl2 on tbl1.id2=tbl2.id2
WHERE order='xyz'
```

I try:

```
obj = tbl1.objects.select_related('id2').filter(order='xyz')
```

I got this error:

FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'order' into field ...

What is wrong ?

thx
Frank

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
obj = tbl1.objects.select_related('id2').filter(id2__order='xyz')
#                                         ------^
```

`relationshipfield__modelfield` is the convention in django to filter on models with which a model has relation.

Should find this in tutorial or reference documents.

Comment: thx, it works. I'am in moment very confused about the "querysets and all around that". I' am good in sql ( also complex sql-statements) but to rebuild this in "queryset-language" it's very hard ;-)